# SharePoint Site Collection Web Analytics reports

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, web-analytics

**Site Collection Web Analytics reports**.

Here am getting the details of `Number of Daily Unique Visitors` & `Number of Page Views` separately.

But I need, who visited the page(Page name) with User details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`Content viewing`** report in [audit log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131#__toc272842194) to view the **users who have viewed content on a site.**

[image]